# Proving my identity in UK via postoffice.co.uk

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, italian-citizens, identification

### Foreword

I have received an e-mail from `noreply@tax.service.gov.uk` with subject *Check your PAYE code change online* which tells me to sign in my ["personal tax account"](https://www.gov.uk/personal-tax-account) to check my details.

### The question

In order to sign in I first need to [prove my identity](https://www.gov.uk/personal-tax-account/sign-in/prove-identity). To do so, I need to create an account. At the end, I need to prove my identity via [postoffice](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/). When doing so, I basically get stuck here:
[image]

The address I've already provided is the only address where I've been living in UK (except for the first month, when I stayed in a suite paied by my company).

What can I do?

Besides, the little warning triangle at the top shows this:

> Operating hours
> Our service desk is providing support under reduced operating hours.
>
> Monday to Friday:
> Phone from 08:00 to 18:00
> Live chat from 08:00 to 22:00
>
> Saturday and Sunday:
> Phone and live chat from 08:00 to 12:00

and now it's 14:16 on Sunday. Does the above mean that something will change on this page tomorrow?

Comment: Are you certain.that the email isn’t a scam? https://www.icpa.org.uk/news/507484/Genuine-HMRC-contact-and-recognising-phishing-emails.htm It sure looks like it could be to me Have you tried checking your PAYE code through the official HMRC site https://www.gov.uk/log-in-register-hmrc-online-services

Comment: Did you actually change your 'PAYE code' beforehand? @Traveller comment would be **very** valid if that is not the case. Such systems are normally self contained (i.e. validation within one application) to avoid scams.

Comment: `noreply@tax.service.gov.uk` is the address I've received the e-mail from. Is it scam?!

Comment: @Enlico I am pretty certain the email is a scam. Use the official HMRC site to check your coding is correct https://www.gov.uk/tax-codes

Comment: @Mark Johnson PAYE codes themselves can’t be changed by individuals, only by HMRC from information provided by eg the employer, or by the individual submitting a tax return. This email is a scam, IMHO, unfortunately

Comment: @Traveller, is _scam_ synonym for _fraud_?

Comment: @Enlico Pretty much. https://www.which.co.uk/consumer-rights/advice/how-to-spot-a-scam

Comment: @Traveller, _**all**_ the links from that e-mail are the same, and they are links to [https://www.gov.uk/](https://www.gov.uk/), and as I wrote I've received the e-mail from `noreply@tax.service.gov.uk`. Can you please tell me if this is compatible with the e-mail being a scam?

Comment: @Enlico I can’t be 100% sure. If the email arrived out of the blue, then I’d be very suspicious. Personally I would **never** click on a link in an email to check my tax code. I would **always** go direct to the HMRC login page, from which you can register and then check your PAYE code and other information.

Comment: @Traveller,The email links only to the official  website gov.uk.

Answer (score 2):

The result from [Verifying the Email - Email Checker](https://email-checker.net/check) for 'noreply@tax.service.gov.uk' is

- `BAD The mailbox doesn't exist.`

<strike>Assume this is a fraud attempt.</strike>
This may be caused by the **noreply** portion, so this method is not conclusive.

> I called HMRC and they've confirmed that the e-mail is authentic, also suggesting that I ask my company for more details about what's happening.

Maybe also a **personal** appointment can be arranged at 'The Post Office' to clarify matters that can't be done online.

As an Italian, you are probably registered in the [Registry of Italians Resident Abroad (A.I.R.E.)](https://www.esteri.it/mae/en/servizi/italiani-all-estero/aire_0.html), which should confirm since when you have been living in the United Kingdom explaining why there is only one address.

---

General rule #1 is **not** to give out personal information over the Internet.

This could be used by others to **impersonate** you

> 'I hereby request, with this varified proof of my identity, that all my money be transferred to the following account in the Caymon Islands... '

You should ask your employer, who uses this [Tax code (PAYE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_code_(PAYE)) number, if everything is correct.

They will probably have a better contact with the HMRC who could determine if this requst **really came from them** or is a scam/fraud attempt.

Comment: I have several legitimate e-mails in my box from some `noreply@some.thing` address for which the link you provided claims they don't exist. Therefore, I'd say that tool is unreliable.

Comment: Furthermore, as I wrote in the question and in the comments, the e-mail is not asking for personal information. It is just giving me links belonging to the (well known) domain [https://www.gov.uk/](https://www.gov.uk/) and telling me I need to take action from there, which I tried to do.

Comment: I called HMRC and they've confirmed that the e-mail is authentic, also suggesting that I ask my company for more details about what's happening.

Comment: @Enlico I have adapted the answer and added some information that might be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I would be very, very, very reluctant to reply to an email that claims to come from HMRC, and I’d definitely not give them any information that they should have or any personal information.

It is most likely a scam. If not then someone at HMRC deserves a kicking for sending email that look like scams.